# Oracle SQL Update Query, looping to limit rows updated at a time

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, limit, rows

I have a query that updates all the past history for a new column. It pulls the values from a source table with a corresponding ID. It also compares an update time with the current time, which may change but for now guarantees this will run on every row.

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.comment = 
   (SELECT table2.comment
    FROM table2
    WHERE table1.ID = table2.ID)
WHERE(SELECT table2.updateTime
FROM table2
WHERE table1.ID = table2.ID) < sysdate
```

There are millions of rows in production and I need to limit this in a loop or something to only update so many at a time. I am fairly new to SQL and have not been able to find any documentation on how a loop would limit the amount of rows updated. How does a loop even know anything about rows in the tables being used?

Comment: You could consider other options as suggested in this AskTom's thread: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6407993912330

Comment: Thanks, that is really interesting, I will have to see what my mentor thinks of that. If it actually works in our case. Seems weird that moving everything to a new table on top of pulling the new column data from the source would be more efficient then just updating one column.

Comment: Being a multi-user environment might also hinder that being an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things...  First, if your tables have primary keys, then this would probably be the preferred update methodology:

```
update (
  select
    t1.comment c1, t2.comment c2
  from
    table1 t1,
    table2 t2
  where
    t1.id = t2.id and
    t2.updateTime < sysdate
)
set
  c1 = c2
```

Second, assuming updateTime means what I would think it means, wouldn't it always be less than sysdate?  Is there a reason to do this?

Third, to minimize the number of unnecessary updates, I would think you could add this.  Assuming only a percentage of rows require update, this should dramatically impact performance.

```
update (
  select
    t1.comment c1, t2.comment c2
  from
    table1 t1,
    table2 t2
  where
    t1.id = t2.id and
    t2.updateTime < sysdate and
  ((t1.comment is null and t2.comment is not null) or
   (t1.comment is not null and t2.comment is null) or
    t1.comment != t2.comment)
)
set
  c1 = c2
```

Finally, I'm not saying a Loop would NEVER help, but I am saying it's generally the wrong approach.  Oracle is tuned to do this sort of thing.  If your update query is slow, it's doubtful wrapping it in a procedural loop will make it run faster.  Updating millions of rows should not be an issue for a well tuned Oracle database.

I understand the thought behind doing this, and it makes sense in a human world.  I've tried it myself only to have a wise Oracle man tell me I was wrong.  When he tuned the update query, it turns out he was quite right.

Comment: Wow, thank you for showing me a much better way of writing this, looks much cleaner and simpler. I realize using sysdate means updating every row every time, just doing what I am told. I kinda figured there would be something else replacing it in the end.

Comment: The DBA's want only 50,000 rows commited at a time, so I am suppose to put it in a loop of sorts. I am new to this but maybe one big commit takes longer then a bunch of smaller ones, or the loop allows other things to happen between each commit.

Comment: I do see what you are saying though and will have to see what my mentor says Monday. You are making me wonder how splitting up the update is more efficient, if it even is.

Comment: With respect,  I think the DBA's limit is a bit rigid.  That said, you could also just add a limit to the inner query to only do 50,000 rows at a time (rownum <= 50000) and run the update until it returns zero rows updated...  Also, I understand the sysdate thing now.  Your original post said that it might be replaced; I just missed it.

Comment: once I figure out why "t1.comment != t2.comment" throws "inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB, inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s" when they are both obviously clobs and the other conditions work. Your query runs on 91 rows vs mine running on all 7000 in the test environment, may convince everyone that the loop is unnecessary.

Comment: Alright cool, assuming I can figure the limit (rownum <= 50000) running until zero syntax, you have answered everything. Very informative thank you very much.

Comment: You have me convinced, ill see what the DBA's say.

Comment: I always forget clobs are funny, "dbms_lob.compare(t1.comment, t2.comment) != 0" works for the last condition. Again thank You.

Comment: Obviously, I didn't realize comment was a lob, but I'm glad you worked through that.  I'm happy this helped